# Can't change the language in Visual Studio Code Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

Due to my location Visual Studio Code was downloaded in Russian. However I need it in English. I've tried everything offered on the website, but nothing works. When I tried to use "locale" there was no such option. Whenever I tried to search for "Configure Language" no such option either.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales#_configure-language-command

Comment: Yea, I did.It didn't work. When I start typing "Conf.." it said no matches found and when I try to put in code it also doesn't recognize it. I've also tried reinstalling it and rebooting my computer obviously, still nothing happens :(

Comment: Can you add a screenshot where no "no matches" dialog shown?

Comment: I added an image to the question

Comment: You are searching it in `settings.json`, you should instead search in `command palette`

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` or `F1` to invoke it

Comment: Thanks, that worked!